# How to create a toolbar in PreferenceScreen?

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

I'm trying to make a Settings activity in my current app that extends from *`AppCompatPreferenceActivity`*. I was able to achieve the desired screen but couldn't create a simple toolbar with back key on it. I've already tried using:

1. inflating custom toolbar
2. using *`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`*  of the `AppCompatPreferenceActivity`

Most of what I'm using came from [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/07/android-implementing-preferences-settings-screen/)!.
I removed the fragment part of it due to the errors it was causing.

Also, I have **NoActionBar** theme.

So far, I have used this in one of my 'about' and 'help' preferences which work flawlessly:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.about));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
```

**UPDATE**:
Got answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55315560/8424340)

Answer (score 0):

Yes when you use `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` for toolbar it should work fine, your implementation seems to be right, but unless your debug or provide the entire code not all could find what the scenario is, also try checking this style.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <!--<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>-->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MaterialDrawer.DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>
    <!--use item name="drawerArrowStyle" if you are using dark primaryColor in your app, else remove it-->
    <style name="MaterialDrawer.DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">false</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

---

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setTitle(getIntent().getExtras().getString("channe_name"));
        toolbar.setSubtitle(getIntent().getExtras().getString("channe_name"));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and also make sure you have the same in xml as well declared

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:background="?colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:ignore="Overdraw"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
```

Comment: _getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)_ gives Null exception. Also, what does the specified **MaterialDrawer.DrawerArrowStyle** do?

Comment: MaterialDrawer.DrawerArrowStyle - style the animated actionbar icons,

Comment: We cannot use _Toolbar_ in a _PreferenceScreen_ xml. If declared in another file, we won't be able to access it using `findViewById()`

Answer (score 0):

## How add AndroidX Toolbar to PreferenceScreen

**settings.xml**

any

**PrefsFragment.java**

```java
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings, rootKey);
    }
}
```

**activity_settings.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/settings_toolbar"
            app:title="@string/header_settings"/>
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/settings_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.settings_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings_content, new PrefsFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: I want to use toolbar in fragment because i'm using different toolbar for every fragment.
have any solution?