# How to create settings screen in android app?

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

How do I create a settings screen? 
Should I use *PreferenceActivity* or  *PreferenceFragment*?

**Note-** Documentation wasn't helpful

What I've already tried:

1. Using *PreferenceActivity* but couldn't implement a simple toolbar in it.
2. Using *PreferenceFragment* but was too complex to understand.

What I want is a simple implementation using *PreferenceFragment*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android 3.0 and later, you should use a PreferenceFragment that displays your app settings.

Create a SettingsFragment:

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      // Load the preferences from an XML resource
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
   }
   ...
}
```

And show it in your activity, like any other fragment:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
      // Display the fragment as the main content.
      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
   }
}
```

You can include a toolbar in your activity xml, and add a container for SettingsFragment under it, this way the toolBar and your SettingsFragment will both be shown)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_catalog_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="-20dp">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_catalog_first_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_catalog_first_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent_background"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            >

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_catalog_fragment_cont"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you don't use androidx (but you'd better use), you can use toolbar in your xml like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.....>
```

Notice: you need to use an attribute  `android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"` (or if you're using the AppCompat library:
`?attr/actionBarSize`) for your fragment container will appear under toolbar

Within your activity don't forget to override onClick() method for your toolbar:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       getActivity().onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't we call `setContentView()` in _SettingsActivity_ ?

Comment: Showing error at line `setContentView()`. Error is _Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar_

Comment: Try to add this dependencies to your gradle file:  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'                       
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'  I'm using androidx library in my project ))) Or you can use a toolBar like this: <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.....> I'll add code in my answer

Comment: Finally! _Toolbar_ is visible but it is overlapping preferences.Tried `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`as you said but not working

Comment: Nice! Now you can mark this answer, as the right one!

Comment: Yup! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a complete working code for implementing settings in android:

add this library to your project

`implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha02'`

- Create **SettingsActivity** and add it to **Manifest**

  ```
  <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"/>
  ```

**activity_preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/color_primary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**SettingsActivity**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        try {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

**SettingsFragment**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String s) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        // implement your settings here
    }
}
```

**preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.preference.PreferenceCategory android:title="General Settings">

        <androidx.preference.Preference
            android:key="general_settings_key"
            android:title="Preference Test" />

        <androidx.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="switch_settings_key"
            android:title="Switch" />

    </androidx.preference.PreferenceCategory>


    <androidx.preference.PreferenceCategory android:title="Other">

        <androidx.preference.Preference
            android:key="about_settings_key"
            android:title="About Me" />


    </androidx.preference.PreferenceCategory>


</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

- Run SettingsActivity and test